# How to fadeout an element after a few second only when it is visible with jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fade

Am trying to Fadeout an element after a few seconds with the following code

```
if(jQuery('.invalidcontent_wrapper').is(':visible')){
     var xSeconds = 4000; 
     setTimeout(function() {
     jQuery('.invalidcontent_wrapper').fadeOut('fast');
  }, xSeconds);
 };
```

But it has a one bug when clicking to the next time and when its opened up it hides quickly.How I can clear somehow the seconds and do this action only that time when the element is shown?

Comment: Where is this `if` statement located?

Comment: "when clicking to the next time" - there no click handler in your provided code.

Comment: its the example , let me add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the `timeout` when user is clicking again,

```
var xSeconds = 4000; 
var timeOut = 0;

jQuery("#someClick").click(function(){
  var elem = jQuery('.invalidcontent_wrapper');
  if(elem.is(':visible')){
   clearTimeout(timeOut);
   timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
     elem.fadeOut('fast');
   }, xSeconds);
  }
});
```

Comment: @AnahitDEV Can you make a small demo of what you are facing in jsfiddle.net ??

Comment: It will be a bit hard, the opening element has an X for closing it and when clikcing on that close and opening it again at that time I see this bug

Comment: Thank you your code worked for me after rechanging my code a bit @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy